# Кодировка при написании HTML-кода — квадратики в браузерах

Tags: html, linux, кодировка

Когда я пишу сайт на html и сохраняю его, запускаю через все возможные браузеры. у меня появляются квадратики вместо текста, почему так происходит? Работаю на Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Save As use!

Comment: я так и делал! Сначало писал название потом точка и потом html

Comment: Исправьте пожалуйста текст вопроса, он содержит орфографические ошибки.

Answer (score 4):

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь проблем нет!!!

Comment: А чтобы httpd отдавал этот Content-Type *в заголовке,* ничего специального не надо?

Answer (score -1):

Решение проблемы дал [@Anton Shevtsov](/users/3274/anton-shevtsov).

Происходит это потому что в лине по умолчанию используется кодировка UTF-8. А в браузерах по умолчанию - windows1251. Вот и получается ерунда. Указанный Антоном тег говорит браузеру, какую кодировку надо использовать.

Еще решение - сохранять написанный HTML-текст в кодировке windows1251.

Comment: ненене, в вин-1251 не нада! Не учите людей плохому!!!

Comment: Правильная информация: умолчание в HTTP — ISO 8859-1, в Linux — вообще никакого (практически ASCII).